# react-datepicker css not being applied

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, symfony, react-datepicker

I'm using a Symfony-based react application and am trying to include a datepicker using the react-datepicker module.

I can create the datepicker object, but it does not appear to be styled correctly - when I click to select the date, there is just a vertical list of numbers that go to the top of the page (I've seen lots of people experience this online, often because they have not imported the datepicker css).

I am importing the react-datepicker.css file and if I inspect my datepicker object in the browser it says: class="react-datepicker-wrapper", so I presume that the import is working.

I am wondering whether I also need to do something else to another file within my application, perhaps to the webpack file, or maybe something else Symfony-related, but I'm a real novice with those things and am a bit stuck.

Your help would be much appreciated! Code below!

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "../../../node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";


class MyWidget extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date()
    }

  }

  handleCalendarClose() {
    console.log("Calendar closed")
  }

  handleCalendarOpen() {
    console.log("Calendar opened")
  }

  setStartDate(startDate) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: startDate
    });

  };


  render() {
    const { startDate } = this.state;

      return (
          <div>
            From: <DatePicker
              selected={startDate}
              onChange={startDate => this.setStartDate(startDate)}
              onCalendarClose={this.handleCalendarClose}
              onCalendarOpen={this.handleCalendarOpen}
            />
          </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: CSS import is simply `import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";`

Comment: Thank you. But this changes nothing. The calendar is still not displayed properly, and yet the object has the class="react-datepicker-wrapper" style in my browser (suggesting the css file has been imported)

Comment: Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/2339

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't find any solution by following that link, but it is the same issue I'm having.

Answer (score 1):

Import like this, it is working for me

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs at: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker

> You will also need to require the CSS file from this package (or
> provide your own). The example below shows how to include the CSS from
> this package if your build system supports requiring CSS files
> (Webpack is one that does).

add this line to your code...
`import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";`

For example...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

// CSS Modules, react-datepicker-cssmodules.css
// import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';

const Example = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)} />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application are using Remix, add in your root file:

```
export const links: LinksFunction = () => [
          {
           rel: "stylesheet", 
           href: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-datepicker/2.14.1/react-datepicker.min.css'
          },
    ]
```

or in Nextjs:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-datepicker/2.14.1/react-datepicker.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the CSS file is not being properly loaded by webpack. You can try importing the CSS file directly into your component using the `style-loader` and `css-loader modules`.

First, install both modules:

```
npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev
```

Then, import the CSS file in your component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import styles from "./MyWidget.module.css";

const MyWidget = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <div className={styles.datePickerWrapper}>
      <DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

export default MyWidget;
In this example, I'm also using a CSS module to apply a custom style to the wrapper div. You can define your own styles in a separate CSS file and import it the same way as the `react-datepicker.css` file.